# sidebar with right 0% to -100% can't hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use below code for my left sidebar and display on a browser is hide/show, but didn't work on the right sidebar
note: sidebar still visible on the browser (button scroll appears)

```
<div id="right-sidebar">
  <div class="content-right">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <p>this column 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>this column 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <p>this column 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button class="close-right" onclick="Toggle()">
      <img src="./images/arrow.png" alt="">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#right-sidebar {
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 900px;
  right: -100%;
  transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -ms-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px gray;
}
```

JS

```
function Toggle(){
  let x = document.getElementById("right-sidebar")
  if ( x.style.right == "0%" ) x.style.right = "-100%";
  else {
    x.style.right = "0%";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use class `hidden` and toggle adding and removing the class?

Comment: You need to change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;`

Comment: finally I can fix my problem with add `max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden` on body